# SQL select statement conditional join

Tags: sql, select

I'm running into a scenario I don't know how to solve.

Here's an example table:

```
items Table
---------------------------------------
id | name  | bool | linked_item_id_fk |
---------------------------------------
1  | test1 | f    | null              |
---------------------------------------
2  | test2 | t    | null              |
---------------------------------------
3  | test3 | t    | 1                 |
---------------------------------------
4  | test4 | f    | 5                 |
---------------------------------------
5  | test5 | f    | null              |
---------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to select data from the table when the bool is true. I'd also like to include items that are linked. Here's an example of what I'm using

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE bool = true
```

This would return:

> test2 and test3

But what I want to get is:

> test1, test2, and test3

In this scenario even though test4 has a linked item, since it is false we don't retrieve test5. But I would like to retrieve test1 since test3 links to it, even though it is false.

Can I do this with a single select statement?

I'm sorry I couldn't come up with a creative title for this question ;)

Comment: Do you need to handle the recursive case where test1 may also be linked to another record (ie: test6) and therefore would also need to be returned?

Comment: No, that is not necessary. I never follow through that far.

Comment: What database is this that allows you to compare linked_item_id_fk (which has values null, 1, and 5) to a boolean?  Doing so, I would expect that only test3 would be returned as 1 would be interpreted as true.

Comment: @MarkLeiber Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will give you the exact records

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE bool = true
 OR ID  IN 
  (Select linked_item_id_fk 
      From items  where bool = true)
```

Comment: "linked_item_id = true" should be changed to "bool = true"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE bool = 't'

UNION ALL

SELECT t2.* FROM Table  t1
JOIN Table t2 ON t1.linked_item_id_fk = t2.id
WHERE t1.bool = 't'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join:

```
select t1.*
from items t1
left join items t2
on t1.id = t2.linked_item_id_fk
where t1.bool = true
or (t2.bool is true and t2.id is not null);
```